# Extract specific HTML container from Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, extract, innerhtml

How would you extract specific html from JS variable that contains html content.

In the example below the JS variable contains the entire html content that was returned from a Fetch API request. I want to just extract the content from the section with class `content`.

**The Variable**

```
const aVariable = fetch(...etc.. etc.. // the returned value)
```

**The returned value contains:**

```
<section class="wrapper">
    blah blah blah
    <div>
        blah blah
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        It's the one that I want
        <div>
            Whoa whoa whoa yeah!
        </div>
    </section>
    blah blah
</section>
```

I just want `content` but inclusive of its `<section>`.

Comment: U have jquery referred?

Comment: @NithinChandran  No. was trying to avoid it. There's a lot more to this and jQuery would really slow it down. This is a backup in case the returned fetch triggered between content being returned. IT's a backup but important.

Comment: Does using `document.querySelector('.content').outerHTML` helps?

Comment: What do you mean by "inclusive of its `<section>`". Everything that's inside the section ?

Comment: Inclusive means he needs the markup of section tag too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DOMParser`.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(aVariable, "text/html");
var elm = doc.querySelector(".content");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) interface

> The `DOMParser` interface provides the ability to parse XML or HTML source code from a string into a DOM Document.

```js
const html = `<section class="wrapper">
    blah blah blah
    <div>
        blah blah
    </div>
    <section class="content">
        It's the one that I want
        <div>
            Whoa whoa whoa yeah!
        </div>
    </section>
    blah blah
</section>`


const domparser = new DOMParser()
const doc = domparser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html')

const elem = doc.querySelector('section.content')

console.log(elem.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work!

```
  var data= $(html);

  var content= data.children('#content').html();
```

Comment: That assumes jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`var all= new DOMParser().parseFromString(aContent) ;`

`var contentHtml = all.querySelector('.content').outerHTML`